# Block Nginx Requests if more than a certain number based on post request(XML)

Tags: xml, post, nginx, centos, ddos

I have been trying to figure out how to block requests based on post xml request. For example below is the format of xml data we receive from a third party service from an integration, now the problem is that at times the third party service sends request pinging location of users almost like a ddos attack resulting in non responsiveness of the server. I don't want to block each every location ping request but only if the request count is too high and that too based on the xml data i.e, I would ideally want to detect only the location ping request coz all of the api post requests come through a single url and post data is dynamic based on the request.

```
      api.test.com/connect/wechat/XXXXXXXXX

      <xml><Event><![CDATA[LOCATION]]></Event><Latitude>39.936901</Latitude><Longitude>116.410301</Longitude><Precision>30.000000</Precision></xml>
```

I hope I am clear enough and any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.